# Ansible: deploy on multiple hosts in the same time

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to run ansible playbook, which looks like this (it is an example from this site: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html):

```
- name: this is a play at the top level of a file
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: say hi
    tags: foo
    shell: echo "hi..."

- include: load_balancers.yml
- include: webservers.yml
- include: dbservers.yml
```

in multithread mode?

I want to run three "includes" in the same time (it is deploying to different hosts anyway), like in this diagram:

http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/5267618

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know if the new [Strategy concept](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html) will work for you. But basically you can change the playbook from linear to free. Also it is a plugin design, so other strategies can be developed.

Comment: The `strategy` concept is provided as an answer below.

Comment: The image in not available anymore. Can you please upload again directly in Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played a long time with things like `ls -1 | xargs -P` to parallelize my playbooks runs. But to get a prettier display, and simplicity I wrote a simple Python tool to do it, [ansible-parallel](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-parallel/).

It goes like this:

```
pip install ansible-parallel
ansible-parallel *.yml
```

To answer precisely to the original question (how to run some tasks first, and the rest in parallel), it can be solved by removing the 3 includes and running:

```
ansible-playbook say_hi.yml
ansible-parallel load_balancers.yml webservers.yml dbservers.yml
```

Answer (score 38):

As of Ansible 2.0 there seems to be an option called `strategy` on a playbook. When setting the strategy to `free`, the playbook plays tasks on each host without waiting to the others. See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_strategies.html.

It looks something like this (taken from the above link):

```
- hosts: all
  strategy: free
  tasks:
  ...
```

Please note that I didn't check this and I'm *very* new to Ansible. I was just curious about doing what you described and happened to come acroess this strategy thing.

EDIT:

It seems like this is not exactly what you're trying to do. Maybe "async tasks" is more appropriate as described here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html.

This includes specifying `async` and `poll` on a task. The following is taken from the 2nd link I mentioned:

```
- name: simulate long running op, allow to run for 45 sec, fire and forget
  command: /bin/sleep 15
  async: 45
  poll: 0
```

I guess you can specify longer `async` times if your task is lengthy. You can probably define your three concurrent task this way.

Comment: This `strategy` solution may only work for tasks in the specific playbook and doesn't seem to work when you `include` several playbooks in a site playbook.

Answer (score 34):

By default Ansible will attempt to run on all hosts in parallel.  See [these Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation-and-parallel-execution) for details.  You can also use the `serial` parameter to limit the number of parallel hosts you want to be processed at any given time, so if you want to have a playbook run on just one host at a time you can specify `serial:1`, etc.

Ansible is designed so that each task will be run on all hosts before continuing on to the next task.  So if you have 3 tasks it will ensure task 1 runs on all your hosts first, then task 2 is run, then task 3 is run.  See [this section of the Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#task-execution) for more details on this.

Comment: That's not what I want. I added diagram which better explains what I want :)

Comment: Currently the only way to get what you want in your diagram would be to run 3 instances of ansible at the same time, one targeting your load balancers, one targeting your web servers, and one targeting your db servers.  

As I said in my answer, Ansible is designed so that a task is run on all appropriate hosts before continuing on to the next task.  If you group disjoint tasks and disjoint servers together in one playbook then Ansible will apply task 1 to server group A first, then task 2 to group A, then task 3 to group B, then task 4 to group B, etc.  It doesn't parallelize based on group.

Comment: But his example is actually very similar to the best practices that Ansible itself gives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158689/ansible-deploy-on-multiple-hosts-in-the-same-time When your site.yml file is just a bunch of includes that themselves are group specific then ansible will process each group in serial instead of parallel. I understand that ansible can't possibly run those tasks in parallel by default, but he's trying to do what they recommend and it's a big limitation that's not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: The `strategy` answer below may be a better answer now that Ansible has added it as a feature.

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned before: By default Ansible will attempt to run on all hosts in parallel, but task after Task(serial).

If you also want to run Tasks in parallel you have to start different instances of ansible.
Here are some ways to to it.

### 1. Groups

If you already have different groups you can run one ansible instance for each group:

```
shell-1 #> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit webservers
shell-2 #> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit dbservers
shell-3 #> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit load_balancers
```

### 2. Multiple shells

#### Playbooks

If your playbooks work standalone you can although do this:

```
shell-1 #> ansible-playbook load_balancers.yml
shell-2 #> ansible-playbook webservers.yml
shell-3 #> ansible-playbook dbservers.yml
```

#### Limit

If not, you can let ansible do the fragmentation.
When you have 6 hosts and want to run 3 instances with 2 host each, you can do something like this:

```
shell-1 #> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit all[0-2]
shell-2 #> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit all[2-4]
shell-3 #> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit all[4-6]
```

### 3. Background

Of course you can use one shell and put the tasks in background, an simple example would be:

```
shell-1 #> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit all[0-2] &
shell-1 #> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit all[2-4] &
shell-1 #> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit all[4-6] &
```

With this method you get all output mixed together in one terminal.
To avoid this you can write the output to different files.

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --limit all[0-2] > log1 &
ansible-playbook site.yml --limit all[2-4] > log2 &
ansible-playbook site.yml --limit all[4-6] > log3 &
```

### 4. Better Solutions

Maybe it's better to use a tool like tmux / screen to start the instances in virtual shells.

Or have a look at the "fireball mode": http://jpmens.net/2012/10/01/dramatically-speeding-up-ansible-runs/

If you want to know more about limits, look here: https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#what-this-organization-enables-examples

Comment: according to http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#what-this-organization-enables-examples the hosts in the parentheses are inclusive so you should do [0-2] [3-5] etc

Comment: The `strategy` answer below may be a better answer now that Ansible has added it as a feature.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I needed the configuration stage to be blocking as a whole, but execute each role in parallel. I've tackled this issue using the following code:

```
echo webserver loadbalancer database | tr ' ' '\n' \
| xargs -I % -P 3 bash -c 'ansible-playbook $1.yml' -- %
```

the -P 3 argument in xargs makes sure that all the commands are ran in parallel, each command executes the respective playbook and the command as a whole blocks until all parts are finished.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible supports patterns which can be used for one/multiple hosts,groups and also can exclude/include groups.
[Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) is the link for official document.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this POC or MVP of running in parallel one-host-from-every-group (for all hosts)
https://github.com/sirkubax/szkolenie3/tree/master/playbooks/playgroups

you may get the inspiration