# ansible parallel deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

After days of research and hitting the brick wall deciding to ask here:
Is it possible to deploy in parallel using single ansible playbook on aws. At the moment deploying EC2 instance takes around 5 minutes for us while RDS takes about 15-20. Is there a way how to deploy all the EC2 instances and RDS instance in parallel. Thanks in advance for the help.
Update:
 Or is there a way for two tasks to be performed at the same time within one host and one playbook

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ansible: deploy on multiple hosts in the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158689/ansible-deploy-on-multiple-hosts-in-the-same-time)

Comment: @slugonamission not really, as there is one host and shared variable. Tried those possible solutions but they not doing what is required. I thought is there something which will allow two tasks to be performed at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into a tool called [Packer](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html)

It states it can "create machine images for multiple platforms in parallel". You can then call ansible to provision the EC2.

If creating a number of similar EC2 instances then try specifying the count property as its within the same task:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html

count no |  1   | number of instances to launch

**EDIT**

In response to the comment can you not set "wait: no" (wait for the AMI to be in state 'available' before returning) when creating the EC2's. You can still register the instances as a variable but ansible will move onto the next task for example the RDS's. To wait for both groups to complete before exiting use a wait_for module and loop through the items for example:

```
- name: Wait for the instances to boot by checking the ssh port
   wait_for: host={{item.private_ip}} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
   with_items: ec2.instances
```

This will spin up all instances concurrently in the background and enable you to provision the EC2's first while waiting for the RDS's to spin up.

Comment: the 3 instances are the same when it comes to config, different when it comes to usage therefore they are build in separate way. the Packer is good for multiple instances at the same time, but I'm looking for RDS at the same time as instances.

Comment: Please see above edit to do RDS at same time as EC2's.