# Ansible: How can I make SSH session persistent?

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Suppose I have a playbook that looks something like the following:

```
- hosts: build-servers
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - role: role1
    - role: role2
    - role: role3
    - role: role4
```

This is executed on one of the multiple build servers connected to a load balancer based on the workload level.

The problem I am facing is that the SSH session to the selected server does not persist until all the tasks are completed. i.e. Ansible initiates a new session to another server even though the tasks are only halfway through.

How can I make sure to get Ansible to keep each session persistent until the entire playbook is executed?

**Edit:**

The following is the end-to-end build workflow that I am following.

**Jenkins -> Ansible -> Build Servers**

When a Jenkins project is initiated, it kicks an Ansible playbook, build.yml shown above, by executing `ansible-playbook build.yml`.
(★Jenkins and Ansible are on the same server)

What I want to achieve is to distribute the workloads(Jenkins projects) among different build servers to accelerate build performance(assuming there are multiple build servers, but only single Jenkins server available).

e.g.

Jenkins(Project1) -> Ansible -> Build Server 1 
Jenkins(Project2) -> Ansible -> Build Server 2 
Jenkins(Project3) -> Ansible -> Build Server 3

Answer (score 2):

Please check the [`ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html) and the `[persistent_connection]` in particular.

It reads:

```
# Configures the persistent connection timeout value in seconds.  This value is
# how long the persistent connection will remain idle before it is destroyed.
# If the connection doesn't receive a request before the timeout value
# expires, the connection is shutdown. The default value is 30 seconds.
#connect_timeout = 30
```

According to it, if you enable the timeout value I guess, the connection will stay open (persistent) and wait for new command(task) for `connect_timeout` seconds. setting it to a great value, you "guarantee" that Ansible won't close the ssh session.

Besides this, you mentioned "Ansible initiates a new session to another server even though the tasks are only halfway through". I believe there is a way to limit the number of runs in parallel - if this is what you want to achieve. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21166909/5736671) will be of use to you.

Comment: Would it be possible to execute playbook only once on a server but not on other servers? i.e. Each Jenkins kick triggers Ansible playbook only once on one of the build servers available.

Comment: you can define the server or group of servers in the `hosts` section of the task, does that help? or you want each role (you have 4 roles in your code) to be executed to a different build server?

Comment: The whole playbook needs to be executed fully on a single server. Ideally, every time Jenkins kicks the Ansible playbook, the whole build process(role1-4) distributed evenly to the build servers available. i.e. instead of executing each role on different build servers, all the roles have to be done on the same build server.

Comment: I think at least on task level run_once can be used to run on the first remote host in the playbook host list https://medium.com/opsops/the-magic-of-run-once-e31d583eca62#:~:text=Deepdive%20into%20Pytest%20parametrization,-Fixture%20parameters%20and%20pytest_generate_tests