# Play and task execution with multiple groups and servers with ansible

Tags: parallel-processing, ansible, execution, inventory

We have this Ansible inventory with dozens of servers, being grouped in servers per microservice. So say we have several application groups in the inventory with servers in it.

Say:

```
[group1]
server1
server2
server3
server20
server27
server38

[group2]
server4
server5

[group3]
server7
server8
server9
server6
```

This inventory is being used for dozens of plays, so just changing it is not an option. I need to deal with this setup.

What I need to know if it is somehow possible to have a play run in parallel on one server in each group without naming them explicitly in the plays? (groups and servers can be added by others and I need to play to be able to cope with that)

So when the play starts it may process in parallel on server1, server4 and server7. Processing on server2 may start when server1 is finished, processing of server5 may start when server4 is finished, etc, etc. You get what I mean I guess. This will mean that, in the beginning, one server of every group is processed, but as time runs by smaller groups will be done whereas in larger group processing still takes place.

Are there ways to achieve this?

Thia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *"**Run in parallel on 1 server in each group ... process in parallel on server1, server4, and server7. Processing on server2 may start when server1 is finished, processing of server5 may start when server4 is finished, etc ...  Iterate over a number of groups and servers unknown at the time of writing the code.**"*

A: As an incomplete hint the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    _groups: "{{ groups.keys()|difference(['all', 'ungrouped']) }}"
#   _hosts: [0, 1, 2]  # Range of minimal common leght perhaps?
    _groups_len_min: "{{ _groups|map('extract', groups)|map('length')|min }}"
    _hosts: "{{ range(_groups_len_min|int) }}"
    my_hosts: "{{ query('cartesian', _hosts, _groups) }}"
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ groups[item.1][item.0] }}"
        groups: my_group
      loop: "{{ my_hosts }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: my_group
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 3  # TODO: Number of the groups involved
  order: inventory
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [my_group] ***************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [server4] => 
  inventory_hostname: server4
ok: [server1] => 
  inventory_hostname: server1
ok: [server7] => 
  inventory_hostname: server7

PLAY [my_group] ***************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [server2] => 
  inventory_hostname: server2
ok: [server5] => 
  inventory_hostname: server5
ok: [server8] => 
  inventory_hostname: server8

PLAY [my_group] ***************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [server6] => 
  inventory_hostname: server6
ok: [server3] => 
  inventory_hostname: server3
ok: [server9] => 
  inventory_hostname: server9
```

If you want to include all hosts fill the missing hosts with *dummies*, e.g. given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[group1]
server1
server2
server3

[group2]
server4
server5

[group3]
server7
```

the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    _groups: "{{ groups.keys()|difference(['all', 'ungrouped']) }}"
    _groups_len_max: "{{ _groups|map('extract', groups)|map('length')|max }}"
    _hosts: "{{ range(_groups_len_max|int) }}"
    my_hosts: "{{ query('cartesian', _hosts, _groups) }}"
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ groups[item.1][item.0]|default('dummy-' ~ ansible_loop.index) }}"
        groups: my_group
      loop: "{{ my_hosts }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      run_once: true

- hosts: my_group
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 3  # TODO: Number of the groups involved
  order: inventory
  tasks:
    - name: Proceed if not dummy
      block:
        - debug:
            var: inventory_hostname
      when: inventory_hostname is not match('^dummy-\d*$')
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [my_group] *****************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [server1] => 
  inventory_hostname: server1
ok: [server4] => 
  inventory_hostname: server4
ok: [server7] => 
  inventory_hostname: server7

PLAY [my_group] *****************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************
skipping: [dummy-6]
ok: [server2] => 
  inventory_hostname: server2
ok: [server5] => 
  inventory_hostname: server5

PLAY [my_group] *****************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [server3] => 
  inventory_hostname: server3
skipping: [dummy-8]
skipping: [dummy-9]
```

---

**NOTES**

A simple option would be creating dynamic groups, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_groups:
      my_group1: [[group1,0], [group2,0], [group3,0]]
      my_group2: [[group1,1], [group2,1], [group3,1]]
      my_group3: [[group1,2], [group2,2], [group3,2]]
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ groups[item.1.0][item.1.1] }}"
        groups: "{{ item.0.key }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_groups|dict2items }}"
        - value
      run_once: true

- hosts: my_group1
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname

- hosts: my_group2
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname

- hosts: my_group3
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [my_group1] *******************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
ok: [server1] => 
  inventory_hostname: server1
ok: [server7] => 
  inventory_hostname: server7
ok: [server4] => 
  inventory_hostname: server4

PLAY [my_group2] *******************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
ok: [server5] => 
  inventory_hostname: server5
ok: [server2] => 
  inventory_hostname: server2
ok: [server8] => 
  inventory_hostname: server8

PLAY [my_group3] *******************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************

ok: [server3] => 
  inventory_hostname: server3
ok: [server6] => 
  inventory_hostname: server6
ok: [server9] => 
  inventory_hostname: server9
```

---

The next option would be creating a single group with the required order of the hosts and set [serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#controlling-playbook-execution-strategies-and-more) and [order](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory), e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_groups:
      my_group1: [[group1,0], [group2,0], [group3,0]]
      my_group2: [[group1,1], [group2,1], [group3,1]]
      my_group3: [[group1,2], [group2,2], [group3,2]]
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ groups[item.1.0][item.1.1] }}"
        groups: my_group
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_groups|dict2items }}"
        - value
      run_once: true

- hosts: my_group
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 3
  order: inventory
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [my_group] ****************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [server1] => 
  inventory_hostname: server1
ok: [server7] => 
  inventory_hostname: server7
ok: [server4] => 
  inventory_hostname: server4

PLAY [my_group] ****************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [server2] => 
  inventory_hostname: server2
ok: [server5] => 
  inventory_hostname: server5
ok: [server8] => 
  inventory_hostname: server8

PLAY [my_group] ****************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [server3] => 
  inventory_hostname: server3
ok: [server6] => 
  inventory_hostname: server6
ok: [server9] => 
  inventory_hostname: server9
```

---

To avoid the tedious job of writing manually a large matrix, it's possible to create the structure dynamically, e.g. the play below creates the same dynamic group

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    _groups: [group1, group2, group3]
    _hosts: [0, 1, 2]
    _dgroups: [my_group1, my_group2, my_group3]
    _groups_hosts: "{{ query('cartesian', _hosts, _groups)|
                       batch(_dgroups|length) }}"
    my_groups: "{{ dict(_dgroups|zip(_groups_hosts)) }}"
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ groups[item.1.1][item.1.0] }}"
        groups: my_group
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_groups|dict2items }}"
        - value
      run_once: true
```

Comment: Thnx. Actually I have been thinking about dynamic groups. However since the inventory can change and multiple people are working on these environments, I need the inventory to be the only place where inventorylike stuff is being stored. So I need to iterate over a, at the time of writing unknown, number of groups with a unknown number is servers in it.

I will change the example in the question to reflect this a bit.

Comment: Get it in the runtime. I've updated the answer.

Comment: If I look at your example, this would mean that if 1 of my groups consists of 48 servers, this would mean I would need 48 _dgroups, right? With 100's of servers it is not really an option to name them all in that vars section, or am i looking at it the wrong way?

What I actually would need in this case is to walk through the inventory and dynamically process what I find there.

Edit:  thnx.   Takes me a week to understand what you are doing here, but I will go and figure out. :-)

Comment: I've updated the answer. I don't know how to dynamically set serial in the 2nd play. The next option would be templating the playbooks.

Comment: I am not there yet, But I want to thank you for your extensive clarification and helpful comments and edits, hence, I do accept this as supportive for a solution already.

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error as soon as I set the upper numbers of _host to bigger then the number of actual hosts in the smalles group. And ignore_errors does not help in this. The play does not fail but execution is halted because of an unfilled variable

Comment: I've updated the code with two options. Both the minimal or maximal length of the groups is used to create the list of the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

there is already an answer on how to run playbooks on multiple hosts answered here [Ansible: deploy on multiple hosts in the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158689/ansible-deploy-on-multiple-hosts-in-the-same-time)

Maybe you could start form there. However if running only first servers in parallel interests you than it will be more difficult, as it would require writing a custom script or something similar

Comment: Thnx, checked those out. Seems rather old stuff, some links are unavailable by now. IT however does not yet quite does what I mean.